# Set object into C array at first available index

Tags: c++, objective-c, c, arrays

I have an array of box2d bodies, initialized like this:

```
b2Body *touchedBodies[10];
```

I need to populate it with several b2Bodies, and I want to set the next b2Body into the first available place -- the place where I haven't put a b2Body yet. So I'm looking for something like this:

```
touchedBodies[touchedBodies->firstOpenSpot()] = someB2Body;
```

Is that possible?

Comment: Not entirely sure if there is a more robust way of doing this, but you could pre-initialize the array with b2Bodies that contain stub information, then check for it. :/  Another way could be to use some sort of integer that keeps track of which elements contain the object, similar to how `chmod` can take a base 10 integer to represent different combinations of read, write, and execute.

Comment: That is an **uninitialized** array of 10 pointers. To initialize all 10 elements to `NULL`, try `b2Body *touchedBodies[10] = {0};`

Comment: What do you intend to do if all places are taken?

Comment: what language is c c++ obective-c?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a dynamic container like the Vector.

You could store the index of the last inserted element.

```
// sample without failsave
int openSpot = 0;

touchedBodies[openSpot] = someB2Body;
openSpot++;
```

You could initialize this array with nullpointer and then iterate through.

```
// sample without failsave
for (int i=0; i < 10; i++) {
    if (touchedBodies[i] != 0) continue;

    touchedBodies[i] = someB2Body;
    break;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @ChriZzZ. I can't use a vector because, for some reason, it doesn't seem that xCode with cocos2d allow for std:: files(unless I'm missing something) but your for loop example works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Introduce a `count`.  Or, initially fill `touchedBodies` with 0, and have the `firstOpenSpot()` search for the first 0.  Make sure to add logic that prevents running further than the size (e.g. using `sizeof` or separate logic/variables).